# inputType="numberDecimal" doesn't accept comma, even when using android:digits="0123456789.,"

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` like this.

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789.," />
```

On most devices it works fine, all the characters specified in `android:digits` are accepted. But on Samsung GT-P5100 (Galaxy Tab 2 10.1) the comma is disabled:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use android:inputType="phone".

Comment: i guess thats based on the devices language, do polish ppl use commas in decimals?

Comment: @UrMi, it worked... Damn, so hacky... Please write an answer, so I can  give you your points :) Yes, in Poland comma is a default separator. But I have polish locale and it doesn't change the default behaviour of keyboard, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use android:inputType="phone". :)

Comment: The other good solution is develop (or find) a fresh new soft keyboard. This grandpa bug is 6 years old and counting. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626

Comment: android:inputType="number"
                    android:digits="0123456789., "